# How to solve "spring crudrepository bean not found" in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I'm relatively new to Spring and have a working project on work machine but am trying to setup the same project on my personal laptop and am having the following issue when starting up my project:

```
Description:
Field productRepository in prs.web.ProductController required a bean of type 'prs.domain.product.ProductRepository' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'prs.domain.product.ProductRepository' in your configuration.
```

I have been through many suggested fixes in stack that have not worked.  This same project works fine on other machines, including peers that have pulled my project, so I believe its something in my configuration.  I'm using the following:
IDE:  Spring Tool Suite
Version: 3.9.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201712210947
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)
OS:  Windows 10

Here is my code:
POM Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

App class - PRSWebApplication:

```
package prs;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PRSWebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PRSWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Entity Class - Product.java

```
package prs.domain.product;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private int vendorID;
    private String partNumber;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private String unit;
    private String photoPath;

    public Product() {
        id = 0;
        vendorID = 0;
        partNumber = "";
        name = "";
        price = 0.0;
        unit = "";
        photoPath = "";
    }
```

Repository: ProductRepository.java

```
package prs.domain.product;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Integer>{

    List<Product> findAllByVendorID(int id);
    List<Product> findAllByVendorIDNot(int id);
}
```

Controller - ProductController.java

```
package prs.web;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import prs.domain.product.Product;
import prs.domain.product.ProductRepository;
import prs.util.PRSMaintenanceReturn;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/Products")
public class ProductController extends BaseController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @GetMapping(path="/List")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Product> getAllProducts() {
        // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }
```

I've seen various fixes that state something about moving my app to a package, but its already in the 'prs' package.  I've also tried various pom file changes and have re-installed Eclipse (various versions but am currently using the STS version noted above).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add @Repository annotation to your dao

Comment: Start the app with debug logging and check the actual stacktrace.

Comment: Where's the configuration for your database connection ? If you replace  the mysql dependency with groupid com.h2database artifact h2 your code works fine and it all starts. I suspect your database connection isn't working, so the repositories don't get created and therefore you have an autowiring problem.

Comment: @PaulNUK if it would have been mysql misconfiguration or no database available situation then the error would have been totally different

Comment: Please post the application log with debug logging turned on.

Comment: Here is link to PRSWebApplication.log with debug on  - https://www.dropbox.com/s/abvqimgcqm1rk1s/PRSWebApplication.log?dl=0

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the `@Repository` annotation to `ProductRepository` ; for now, you try to autowired a class that isn't a bean, thus the error.

Comment: No you don't that's not needed. The repository beans are created via the EnableJpaRepositories annotation, which scans for interfaces of the correct type and creates a bean that is a proxy of the interface with all the repository code fleshed out.

Comment: No it needs neither repository or component - see the Spring Data JPA docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories

Comment: I would have agree with this if the Repository wasn't autowired. In my comprehension of spring, you should always at least put `@Component` when you try to autowired a bean.

Comment: Well OP is missing EnableJpaRepostories annotation also

Comment: @Sikorski - as pointed out to me by M Denium, this isn't need as SpringBootApplication autoconfigures the repository initialisation.

Comment: No it doesn't need `@Repository` read the docs you refer to. The same goes for `@EnableJpaRepository` that already is enabled by Spring Boot for you. If you give advice please read up on the frameworks used.